# How to resolve an error of GraphQL error: id missing in object false when re-assigning a var due a condition stament

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

In one service which uses GraphQL, Apollo and NodeJS I'm trying to assign to a specific variable the value of false based of a condition.

I have this situation where some data from DB can be undefined and if so I need to put false on a variable as that will mean is disable.

The below code is about this and after the code snippet the explanation:

```
updateStudy({ input }) {
    const { UserInputError } = this.errors;
    return this.withDAO(async ({ studies, featureOptions }) => {
      const study = await studies.selectById(input.id);
      if (!study)
        throw new UserInputError(`Study id ${input.id} doesn't exists.`);

      const featOptions = await featureOptions.selectFirst({ studyId: study.id });

      let featEngagementPortal = true;
      if (!featOptions) {
        featEngagementPortal = false;
        return featEngagementPortal
      }
```

In this code the `const featOptions` can be `undefined` because there ae studies which they not have `featureOptions`

So what I tried to do is that if I don't have `featOptions` assign `featEngagementPortal = false` so this particular feature is disable.

Running this causing the following error:

```
GraphQL error: id missing in object false
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but cannot rid off of this error.
I need it as in the missing part of the code here, I have to do some operations based on true/false of the EngagementPortal.

Answer (score 0):

From `updateStudy` your returning only `featEngagementPortal`. I'm guessing you want to merge with the study object, in some way, as suggested by the missing `id` graph is expecting on return type:

```
     ...

     return Object.assign({}, { featEngagementPortal }, study);
```